# golden ratio calculation with precision

Tags: java, bigdecimal, mathcontext

I've got the task to calculate the golden ratio (phi = (1+ sqrt(5))/2).
But I need to calculate it with about 50 decimal digits / decimal places and then round the result up to 30 decimal digits and print it on the console. I am allowed to use BigDecimal and MathContext.
Does anyone have an idea how to calculate it? I am lost right now.
Thanks

Comment: Problems have subproblems. There are several here, including using BigDecimal, doing addition, subtract, and division with BigDecimal. Another big subproblem is computing square roots using BigDecimal. Saying you're lost does not allow people to help you, you need to be specific about what part of the problem has you stumped and why.

Answer (score 3):

I won't try to solve your problem for you!
However I think to point you in a promising direction would be to look at the API:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
and specifically at the constructor:
`BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale, MathContext mc)`
I believe that if you experiment with these objects you can meet your goal.
Note: sqrt was only added to `BigDecimal` in Java 9.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the web. It can be used to verify your calculations.

```
String goldenRatio = 
"1.61803398874989484820458683436563811772030917980576286213544862270526046281890" +
"244970720720418939113748475408807538689175212663386222353693179318006076672635";
```

You can verify the correctness of a regular calculation by

- Verifying the length (don't forget the decimal point and the whole number digits).
- verifying that it matches some initial part of the supplied answer.

To calculate normally, I used `MathContext` of precision = `30` and `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`.

This may not work for the way you are expected to do it.  If you run into problems, folks here will be able to help.

I strongly suggest you post an attempt before asking for any additional help though.